# Facebook LikeView causes a crash in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like, android-dialog

I'm adding a Facebook LikeView to my app, and when I put it inside a dialog, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
at com.facebook.widget.LikeView.toggleLike(LikeView.java:467)
at com.facebook.widget.LikeView.access$6(LikeView.java:465)
at com.facebook.widget.LikeView$1.onClick(LikeView.java:430)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3540)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14167)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4532)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
```

If I add it to an activity, it works ok. Any ideas, what's the problem?

**EDIT:**

This is the code I'm working on:

This is my dialog's xml:

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 <com.facebook.widget.LikeView
        android:id="@+id/btn_fb_like"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The LikeDialog code:

```html
    public class LikeDialog extends Dialog {

 public LikeDialog(Context context) {
  super(context);
  
  setContentView(R.layout.like_dialog);
  ((LikeView) findViewById(R.id.btn_fb_like)).setObjectId("URL_TO_MY_FACEBOOK_PAGE");
 }
}
```

And finally my MainActivity:

```html
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  Settings.sdkInitialize(this);
  
  LikeDialog likeDialog = new LikeDialog(this);
  likeDialog.show();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  LikeView.handleOnActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }
}
```

Comment: show related part of code

Comment: Having the button in a Dialog is not currently supported. You can file a bug at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mLikeOnFacebook = (LikeView) view.findViewById(R.id.b_like_facebook);
    mLikeOnFacebook.setObjectIdAndType("Link to page", LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);
}
```